# How can I configure spark so that it creates "_$folder$" entries in S3?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

When I write my dataframe to S3 using

```
df.write
  .format("parquet")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour", "gen", "client")
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .save("s3://xxxx/yyyy")
```

I get the following in S3

```
year=2018
year=2019
```

but I would like to have this instead:

```
year=2018
year=2018_$folder$
year=2019
year=2019_$folder$
```

The scripts that are reading from that S3 location depend on the `*_$folder$` entries, but I haven't found a way to configure spark/hadoop to generate them.

Any idea on what hadoop or spark configuration setting control the generation of `*_$folder$` files?

Comment: I have the opposite scenario , where the Spark context in Glue , generates those empty folders and I am trying to figure out how to disable the creating process...  Why do you want the spark to generate those folders? Are they useful? For later analytics? performance? Should I keep them or it is ok to remove with a lambda function?[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65667996/how-to-configure-spark-glue-to-avoid-creation-of-empty-folder-after-glue-j?noredirect=1#comment116124035_65667996) is the issue that I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those markers a legacy feature; I don't think anything creates them any more...though they are often ignored when actually listing directories. (that is, even if there, they get stripped from listings and replaced with directory entries).

Comment: i'm using EMR-6.4.0 (Spark 3.1.2) and i'm still suffering from them. to make thinks even worse, it's not consistent, meaning not all s3 folders have the `*_$folder$`, only like 80% of them have it